# Android emulator system partition no space from start

Tags: android, emulation, adb

I have a weird problem with the Android emulator. I have created a virtual device through Android AVD manager (newly created emulator with platform 2.1 and API level 7). I have tried with standard settings and with added hardware parameter for larger (256 MB) device RAM size but nothing changed.

I need to come files to the system partition to test a project (called haggle), but for some reason the system partition has no space from start.

```
aa a@aaa /home/haggle-0.2-android
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell

 # df
df
/dev: 47084K total, 0K used, 47084K available (block size 4096)
/sqlite_stmt_journals: 4096K total, 0K used, 4096K available (block size 4096)
/system: 73600K total, 73600K used, 0K available (block size 4096)
/data: 65536K total, 18464K used, 47072K available (block size 4096)
/cache: 65536K total, 1156K used, 64380K available (block size 4096)
```

As you can see the system partition has 0K space available. When a connect a non-rooted HTC Nexus One and do the same I get these values:

```
/dev: 108896K total, 0K used, 108896K available (block size 4096)
/sqlite_stmt_journals: 4096K total, 0K used, 4096K available (block size 4096)
/system: 148480K total, 116364K used, 32116K available (block size 4096)
/data: 200960K total, 22296K used, 178664K available (block size 4096)
/cache: 97280K total, 1852K used, 95428K available (block size 4096)
/sdcard: 3864064K total, 118496K used, 3745568K available (block size 32768)
```

Why does the system partition on the emulator have 0K free space from beginning, and what can I do to change that? Even if I make the partition write-able with mount/remount I get the same 0K values.

Any tips?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the answer :)

When starting the emulator you can specify the partition size by -partition-size x emulator_name.

done through the terminal that is.
Example:

```
emulator -partition-size 125 @AVD1
```

OR

```
emulator -partition-size 125 -avd AVD1
```

Note that the size must be bigger than your current system partition size.
For the Android4.0.3 emulator the default size is already 168 so set your new partition-size to something bigger like 256

Comment: any way to do this through the AVD Manager?

Comment: Alt syntax: emulator -partition-size 125 -avd AVD1

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays, `-partition-size` changes the /system/data partition, but not the /system partition space.

If you want to install the full GApps, for example, you will need more space.

The general procedure to do so in Unix is documented at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104790/how-to-setup-a-growable-loopback-device

In short:

1. Make a copy of system.img so that you don't modify the original one in the SDK (`cp system.img system-extended.img`)
2. Grow your `system-extended.img` to your desired size (e.g., `truncate system-extended.img -s 2G`)
3. Resize the inner ext4 filesystem (`resizefs system-extended.img` OR `resize2fs system-extended.img`)
4. Use the new img file when calling the emulator via the `-system <path/to/system-extended.img>` parameter. The `-writable-system` parameter may also come in handy for you.

Comment: This answer should be the ACCEPTED answer, as it's the only one that allows to increase the '/sytem' partition size.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem trying @ssice's answer on Android Q (Android TV if that matters).

Apparently the system.img is now a GPT partitioned disk image.

You can confirm this by running `file system.img`:

```
system.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x87,130,59), startsector 1, 2177023 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

If this is also the case for you, here's what you can do on Linux:

1. Resize system.img: `truncate -s 3G system.img`
2. Recreate the partition table and create a partition that spans across it:

   - `fdisk system.img`
   - `g` for new GPT partition table
   - `n` for a new partition. choose partition number 1; accept defaults for a partition that will span the entire disk
   - `w` for saving the changes

```
$ fdisk system.img

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): g
Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: 2E6B87B6-5492-47E0-A164-A148E24445A0).

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1):
First sector (2048-6291422, default 2048):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-6291422, default 6291422):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 3 GiB.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

3. Mount `system.img` as a loopback device

   - `losetup -fP system.img`
   - grab allocated `/dev/loopN` (for example, `/dev/loop1`) from `losetup -a | grep system.img`
4. Resize filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/loop1p1` (`/dev/loop1` partition 1)

Answer (score 1):

For Android 10 emulator built from sources the following solutions works well:

```
$ emulator -partition-size 8192 -writable-system
```

If an emulator has been launched before it is necessary to clear out and rebuild it again:

```
$ make installclean
$ rm out/target/product/generic_x86_64/*qcow2
$ make
$ emulator -partition-size 8192 -writable-system
```

Successfully tested on the **aosp_car_x86_64** target.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The **SDK_MANAGER** folder was inside a NON-STANDARD characters directory in my D disk (`D:/ასერ/?dwe + joan/SKD_MANAGER`)
and thats why it couldnt get the correct partition size. I moved  **SDK_MANAGER* to D:/**SDK_MANAGER* and problem solved!

( so, who has the error messages like "Invalid system partition size" or "panick: could not open avd1", this post might help)