# Can't increase size of /system/ of the emulated virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

Under Windows 10, in Android Studio, I create a virtual device - Nexus 5X, with the system image of Android 6.0, x86_64, API v 23. Tried with two sets of parameters: with all defaults (RAM 1536 MB, VM heap 228 MB, Internal Storage 800 MB, SD 512 MB - below called "Nexus5Xv23small"), and with all sizes increased (RAM 3 GB, VM heap 512 MB, Internal Storage 2 GB, SD 1 GB - below called "Nexus5Xv23big").
Then I run it with the following parameters:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus5Xv23small -no-audio -no-boot-anim -writable-system
```

Then I run

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Then, in `adb shell`, I check sizes  with `df`:

```
root@generic_x86_64:/ # df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   749.2M    52.0K   749.2M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         749.2M    12.0K   749.2M   4096
/mnt                   749.2M     0.0K   749.2M   4096
/system                  1.5G     1.4G    71.3M   4096
/cache                  61.0M    64.0K    60.9M   4096
/storage               749.2M     0.0K   749.2M   4096
/data                  774.9M   235.5M   539.4M   4096
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated   774.9M   235.5M   539.4M   4096
/storage/emulated      774.9M   235.5M   539.4M   4096
/mnt/runtime/read/emulated   774.9M   235.5M   539.4M   4096
/mnt/runtime/write/emulated   774.9M   235.5M   539.4M   4096
/mnt/media_rw/0808-4103   510.0M    22.0K   510.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/default/0808-4103   510.0M    22.0K   510.0M   2048
/storage/0808-4103     510.0M    22.0K   510.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/read/0808-4103   510.0M    22.0K   510.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/write/0808-4103   510.0M    22.0K   510.0M   2048
```

`/system` has only 71M free left. To my surprise, "bigger" image didn't solve this problem:

```
root@generic_x86_64:/ # df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                     1.5G    52.0K     1.5G   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup           1.5G    12.0K     1.5G   4096
/mnt                     1.5G     0.0K     1.5G   4096
/system                  1.5G     1.4G    71.3M   4096
/cache                  61.0M    64.0K    60.9M   4096
/storage                 1.5G     0.0K     1.5G   4096
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated     1.9G   156.6M     1.8G   4096
/storage/emulated        1.9G   156.6M     1.8G   4096
/mnt/runtime/read/emulated     1.9G   156.6M     1.8G   4096
/mnt/runtime/write/emulated     1.9G   156.6M     1.8G   4096
/mnt/media_rw/080B-3903  1020.0M     4.0K  1020.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/default/080B-3903  1020.0M     4.0K  1020.0M   2048
/storage/080B-3903    1020.0M     4.0K  1020.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/read/080B-3903  1020.0M     4.0K  1020.0M   2048
/mnt/runtime/write/080B-3903  1020.0M     4.0K  1020.0M   2048
/data                    1.9G   156.6M     1.8G   4096
```

You can see that `/dev`, `/mnt`, `/storage`, `/data` are indeed increased, but `/system` remains the same.

I tried running with `-partition-size` parameter, something like this:
`emulator -avd Nexus5Xv23small -partition-size 2047 -no-audio -no-boot-anim -writable-system -no-snapshot-load` - but this seems to affect only `/data`, `/storage/emulated` and `/mnt/runtime/*/emulated`.

I found an old SO post "[Android emulator system partition no space from start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675380/android-emulator-system-partition-no-space-from-start)" where one of the answers says that "Nowadays, `-partition-size` changes the `/system/data` partition, but not the `/system` partition space" and suggests manually increasing the size of `system.img`. Well, in my case I don't see neither `/system/data` at my device nor `system.img` in my avd (I have cache.img, encryptionkey.img, sdcard.img, userdata.img, userdata-qemu.img). 
Would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: I'm facing this very same problem