# No space left on device when I install a apk use adb

Tags: android, adb, emulation

I have started an Android emulator, I have started getting the following error [image] when i use `adb` to install a `apk` and this `apk`'s size is only 1M.

There is enough space in data partition. [image]

Can anyone suggest a reason this might be happening?

Comment: This other question might come handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332797/no-space-left-on-android-emulator

Comment: Thanks a lot. There are some difference with that question. I'm still looking for a solution.