# How to get Google Play store in Lollipop API level 22 (x86_64) in android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I need to use google play store in Android emulator-AVD using Lollipop API level 22 (x86_64).

I have gone through this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23)  which suggested to install the pico version for android v5.1 of https://opengapps.org/.

I have referred the below medium posts to install opengapps :

1. https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1
2. https://medium.com/@yjwong/installing-google-apps-on-vs-emulator-for-android-6abe9c7167f4

AVD seems to run out of space and get this error during the process..

```
adb push priv-app /system
adb: error: failed to copy 'priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk' to '/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk': remote No space left on device
```

I tried to expand the system image referring to these articles.

http://azertech.net/content/kvm-qemu-qcow2-qemu-img-and-snapshots.

StackOverflow - [No space left on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332797/no-space-left-on-android-emulator).

How do I get Google play store to work in Android 5.1?

Edit:
I need to check es6 compatibility for the default Android System WebView in Android Lollipop and find out if updating it improves es6 support.

Update:
I checked with an actual device. Updating Webview and google chrome improved es6 support.

Comment: i think that the system.img should be expanded, in android studio system.img comes with a few megs of free space, doing that on windows10 is something i haven't figured out